# Image uploading and inserting name to database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to upload the image in the folder and insert its name in database. Something like this `C:\xampp\tmp\phpAA38.tmp` is stored in database instead of image name and nothing is uploaded.

```
 $imageName = $request->file('image');
    if($imageName!==null)
    {
        $imageName->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $imageName->move(
            base_path() . '/public/images/new', $imageName);
    }
    $store= Result::insert(['Name'=>$name,Image'=>$imageName]);
```

i ensured the form accepts the files using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code. E.g.

- You're not saving or using the file extension
- You're not moving the file correctly

See if this works better:

```
$imageName = $request->file('image');
if($imageName!==null)
{
    // get the extension
    $extension = $imageName->getClientOriginalExtension();
    // create a new file name
    $new_name = date( 'Y-m-d' ) . '-' . str_random( 10 ) . '.' . $extension;
    // move file to public/images/new and use $new_name
    $imageName->move( public_path('images/new'), $imageName);
}
$store= Result::insert(['Name'=>$name,Image'=>$new_name]);
```

Comment: image name is inserted with new name but the image is not uploaded in the directory.

Comment: ok. it should have been`$imageName->move( public_path('images/new'), $new_name);`?

Comment: Image is uploaded to temporary directory. You need to use `move()` to move it into public directory. In my example, I also give it a new name to avoid conflicts.